# Question about openSuse server

Tags: system-installation, opensuse

Just wondering. Does openSUSE allow to perform a minimal (server-like) installation? (No GUI for end-users, Just like Debian and CentOS with their minimal ISOs)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. During installation, on the **Desktop Selection** page, choose **Other**, then **Minimal Server Selection (Text Mode)**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they do, it is easily available through the desktop selection page, as Mark Plotnick said; however, if you want to completely customize your iso you might want to check out [SuSE Studio](https://susestudio.com/).